# Websphere 8.5 Session deadlock

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

I am using Websphere 8.5 as my webserver, its an clustered environment, and its was accessing by high number of users using the sessions, when user access increase we are receiving the following error with session object,

```
Thread "WebContainer : 10" (00000092) has been active for 779518 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 8 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
        at com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession.updateLastAccessTime(MemorySession.java:638)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemoryStore.getSession(MemoryStore.java:194)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemoryStore.getSession(MemoryStore.java:712)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManager.getSessionFromStore(SessionManager.java:497)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:476)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:462)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:693)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.getIHttpSession(SessionContext.java:473)
        at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.sessionPreInvoke(SessionContext.java:630)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTRequestContext.sessionPreInvoke(SRTRequestContext.java:64)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sessionPreInvoke(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:281)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.preInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelper.java:473)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1086)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
```

Which is causing the my web-server to get hung and cannot process further request. as intermittent solution i am restarting the nodes which is not good practice, since there are numerous number of users accessing the system , looking forward to get an response.

Comment: Have you opened a support case with IBM? This does not really same like q&a.

Comment: Nope i haven't consult IBM support yet.